# Ontener id de video de Dailymotion con API PHP

Tags: php, api

Estoy utilizando la API de `dailymotion` para subir videos pero quiero obtener el id del video recién subido pero no se como hacerlo. Alguien me podría ayudar??

Tengo este código:

```
$api->setGrantType(
                    Dailymotion::GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD,
                    $apiKey,
                    $apiSecret,
                    array('write', 'delete', 'manage_videos'), // OAuth 2.0 scopes that you'd like to be granted by the end-user
                    array(
                        'username' => dailymotion_uname, // don't forget to sanitize this,
                        'password' => dailymotion_password, // never use POST variables this way
                    )
                );


             // $data['video_id'] = "test";

                $url = $api->uploadFile( getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."video".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$data['video_id'].".mp4");
                $api->post(
                    '/me/videos',
                    array(
                        'url'       => $url,
                        'title'     => $data['title'],
                        'description'      => $data['info'],
                        'channel'   => dailymotion_channel,
                        'published' => true,
                    )

                );
```

Si alguien me quiere ayudar les dejo la documentación de la api :

https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#getting-started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La api de dailymotion no es muy clara al respecto, pero lo que estás haciendo es correcto, sólo te falta leer la respuesta.

```
$url = $api->uploadFile( getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."video".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$data['video_id'].".mp4");
$respuesta = $api->post(
                '/me/videos',
                array(
                    'url'       => $url,
                    'title'     => $data['title'],
                    'description'      => $data['info'],
                    'channel'   => dailymotion_channel,
                    'published' => true,
                )
            );
$video_id = $respuesta['id']
```

Como la documentación te dice, `uploadFile` hace la subida del archivo y te devuelve una url para que puedas publicarla con el método ->`post().` este api->post es el que devuelve el id del vídeo ya publicado.

Te diría que hagas un `print_r($respuesta)` para ver todas las variables que devuelve, no estoy seguro que devuelve en caso de error, seguro tenes que hacer catch de `DailymotionApiException`, pero si lo quieres hacer simple podrías preguntar si `isset($respuesta['id'])`.

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Creo que la variable 'ID' no esta SET, me da error y cuando ago el print_r me devuelve esta cadena de texto http://upload-02.sv6.dailymotion.com/files/846044c296867ea90cbad13cf0262411.mp4#YWNvZGVjPUFBQyZiaXRyYXRlPTIxOTM5NjImZGltZW5zaW9uPTEyODB4NzIwJmR1cmF0aW9uPTY2MDUzOCZmb3JtYXQ9TVBFRy00Jmhhc2g9MDg0ZWZhY2ZkN2QyNmYyOTA3NTA0ODIxY2E2OTA2ZDU3NjQ5ZmRjNSZuYW1lPXk0QnZDaVRHUHN3JnNlYWw9ZDkzYTMyMTEyYmQxYjEyMmVkMTYzYjU1YTE1ZWRkNWQmc2l6ZT0xODExNDk0NTEmc3RyZWFtYWJsZT1ZZXMmdmNvZGVjPUFWQw==

Comment: @JoseRodriguez estas haciendo print_r de $url, tenes que hacer print_r de $respuesta, escribiste el código como lo puse?

Comment: Tienes razón,  ya lo arregle y si funcionó. Muchas gracias!!!